# Convert TFS project to branch structure

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops

I have recently joined a company who use no branching strategy.  I'd like to implement a basic branching strategy along the lines of a branch per large User Story, a stable main branch, and a release branch.

The problem I have right now is that currently no branch exists.  All the code and folders are directly nested underneath the project in TFS.

Ideally I'd like to move that into a "MAIN" branch and then branch off as I see fit. But I do not know how to perform the manoeuvre to move everything initial branch.

If it helps, I am using VS 2015 and Visual Studio Team Services (was TFS Online).

Here is an example of how things look at the moment

- ourname.visualstudio.com

  - Our Project

    - Code Folder1
    - Code Folder2
    - Code Folder3
    - Code Folder4

Ideally I'd like this to be

- ourname.visualstudio.com

  - Our Project

    - Main (branch)

      - Code Folder1
      - Code Folder2
      - Code Folder3
      - Code Folder4
    - Dev (branch)

      - Code Folder1
      - Code Folder2
      - Code Folder3
      - Code Folder4

Answer (score 0):

Within the Source Control Explorer in Visual Studio, make a new folder for your branch, then right-click -> "Move" things into it. Then you can create a branch off of that folder.

Comment: I thought branches and folders were actually different things so you couldnt do this?

Comment: You need a folder so you can "Conver folder to Branch" in Source Control Explorer

Comment: Is that serious that I have to move every single file or folder one by one? I cant just select a bunch of files or folders and "move"? Am I missing something? Because as soon as I select more than one item in the Source Control Explorer, "Move" is unavailable.